# Teclado numérico no input type="Text", ionic cordova

Tags: android, ios, ionic, mobile, cordova-plugin

Possuo em meu app um campo para cpf, preciso fazer com que quando o usuario for preencher o cpf, o dispositivo mostre apenas o teclado numérico. Porem se eu alterar o `<input type="text">` para `<input type="number">`, o teclado numérico aparecem, porem não me permite digitar o cpf corretamente, pois cfp não é exatamente um número.

Este problema ocorre também com Cep, Cnpj, Telefone.

Existe alguma forma de indicar para o ionic que aquele input deve habilitar o teclado numérico, que não seja alterando o `<input type>` para *number*?

Comment: cara use o Jquery Mask muito top fácil de implementar https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 1):

O type Tel trás o teclado numérico para o mobile como o da parte de discagem.

```
<input type="tel">
```